# Help in forming a correctly "weighted" rating.

Tags: probability, numerical-methods

I  am at my wits end and hoping someone can help out.

My problem is how to apply a correctly weighted Numerical Rating based upon a calculated % Strike Rate.

Example; if TRNR1 has 49 wins from 490 runners for a strike rate of 10% and TRNR2 has 1 win from 10 runners for 10%, I allocate a much higher end rating to TRNR 1, my logic being that the greater run / win numbers of TRNR 1 provide for a more accurate indication of future results. I also apply this same logic when a TRNR3 has 0 wins from 50 runners and TRNR4 has 0 wins from 1 runner (both 0% strike rate), I provide a much lower negative rating to TRNR3.
My dilemma however is that these ratings are based on no mathematical formula, they are merely my own judgemental figures.

My question- Is there a known  mathematical formula(s) or a correct way to create a numerical rating which takes into account the number of runs and wins, thus producing a correctly ‘”weighted” rating in either a positive or negative range.

Thanks.

I'll try and ask my question in a different way. If I have 3 datasets that produce end results of 1/10, 10/100, 100/1000 all =10%, however in terms of future probability is the 100/1000 more of an accurate indicator than the 1/10, and if so, how would you measure that level of accuracy. If I had to apply a numerical rating (to measure this accuracy) between +10 to -10, is there a formula or a correct method to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is no "correct mathematical way" to do this. If you [edit] the question to show us the range of ratings you desire (lowest to highest possible) and your intuition about where your examples (more than just the four you have already) fall in that range we may be able to suggest a formula that approximates what you want.

Comment: Thank you for replies, I'll try and ask my question in a different way. If I have 3 datasets that produce end results of  1/10, 10/100, 100/1000 all =10%, however in terms of future probability is the 100/1000 more of an accurate indicator than the 1/10, and if so, how would you measure that level of accuracy. If I had to apply a numerical rating (to measure this accuracy) between +10 to -10, is there a formula or a correct method to achieve this. Thanks.